# numpy vectorize sums over lists of indices

Tags: numpy, vectorization

Is there some way to vectorize this for loop?
Lc is a vector, Lr is a 2D array

```
    for j in range(n):
        Mj = Nodes[j] # Mj is a list of indices to sum over

        L_posteriori[j] = Lc[j] + sum(Lr[Mj,j])
```

This loop is producing a sum over a list of row indices for each column, the row indices being different for each column

Comment: Can you provide some example data for `Lc` & `Lr`? ]

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you? Accept if it did?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

Use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to generate all of `Lr[Mj,j]` in one-go, sum along its rows and then perform addition with `Lc` -

```
B = Lr[Nodes, np.arange(len(Nodes))[:,None]]
L_posteriori = Lc + B.sum(1,keepdims=1)
```

**Approach #2**

Those indices could be translated to a boolean array of matches against the range of indices covering the length of the array that we are indexing into, i.e. `Lr`. Then, we get those sum of rows off `B` directly with a tensor sum-reduction using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), like so -

```
mask = Nodes == np.arange(len(Lr))[:,None,None]
B_rowsum = np.einsum('ij,ijk->j',Lr,mask)
```

So, add `Lc` with `B_rowsum` for the desired output -

```
L_posteriori = Lc + B_rowsum[:,None]
```